# How to create a custom template with grid kendo and ngx formly?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, ngx-formly

Im using kedo grid and ngx formly to display data.

There are 4 files. kedo.ts and kedo.html for custom template and the
component.html and component.ts to use the template.
Im have tried to simplify as much as possible the code but still data are undefined.

kedo.ts

```html
<kendo-grid 
[kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
[formlyAttributes]="field">

  <kendo-grid-column 
  *ngFor="let column of columns" 
  [field]="to.columns">
      <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
      <span [class.special]="column.field === 'CompanyName'">  {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})</span>
      </ng-template>
         <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <span [class.special]="column === 'CompanyName'">  {{dataItem[column]}}</span>
      </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

kedo.ts

```js
export class DatatableFormComponentKendo extends FieldArrayType implements OnInit { 

}

  private gridData: any[] //= sampleCustomers; if uncoment here in the grid data will be displayed. 
constructor() {
    super(); 
  }
```

component.ts

```js
  private gridData: any[] = sampleCustomers;
  public columns: any[] = [{ field: 'ProductName', title: 'Name'}, { }];


  fieldsTable: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [{
    key: 'gridData',
    type: 'datatable-kendo',
    templateOptions: {
      column: [
        { field: 'actions'},
        { field: 'id'},       

      ],
}
```

component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm(data)" class="py-3">
    <formly-form [model]="modelTable" [fields]="fieldsTable" [options]="options" [form]="form">
    </formly-form>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice, I was about to start this component, will try to run your code and see what I find

Comment: I couldn't make your example run properly, seems that you ommited some code, can you put your example in a stackblitz or something like that?

Comment: Already its not possible to use kendogrid with FormlyFieldConfig. Somehow kendo its not customizable. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: if you manage to make this example run in a stackblitz i'll help make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a kendo grid and kendo tree list component for formly, just posted it on github, you can give some time and ideas for it on the github issue

https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/2371

but I think that this component solve your problem

Comment: now there is this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@luizfbicalho/ngx-formly-kendo-extras